# JPA Eclipselink Multitenant, table doesn't exist error

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, eclipselink, multi-tenant

i'm trying to make a simple multitenant example to run, using Eclipselink 2.5.2, and MySQL.

When trying to persist an entity asigned to a tenant id, mysql server throws an error: "Table 'jpatest.tenant1_userdata' doesn't exist". (userdata being the entity, jpatest the database name, and tenant1 the tenant-id)

The table indeed doesn't exist, the database jpatest do exist. I was expecting eclipselink to autogenerate the tables each time i try to persist with a new tenant id.

So the question would be:
How can i force Eclipselink to create the tables?
If that is not possible; How can i create tables at runtime?

Here's the code:

Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "userdata")
@Multitenant(value = MultitenantType.TABLE_PER_TENANT)
@TenantTableDiscriminator(type = TenantTableDiscriminatorType.PREFIX, contextProperty = "tenant-id")
public class UserData implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String name;

.
.
.
```

persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="MultiTeanantTest" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <class>UserData</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jpatest" />

            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.create-database-schemas" value="true"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Main class:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        UserData ud = new UserData();
        ud.setNombre("John);
        Map properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put("tenant-id", "tenant1");

        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("MultiTeanantTest", properties );
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.persist(ud);
        em.getTransaction().commit();

    }

}
```

Hope someone can give me a tip in what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: Table creation is meant for development and only runs once, upfront when the persistence unit is deployed and the tenant information isn't available.  You will need to pre-generate scripts -JPA can generate the scripts initially for you, and then you modify them so they can be executed with the tenant data later on.

Answer (score 0):

DDL generation will not be supported in a Multitenant Scenario by Eclipselink.

Refer to this link for more information, https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/DesignDocs/Multi-Tenancy/TablePerTenant

Comment: I have a problem with the generation of table, i was expecting to autogenerate the tables each time there is a new tenant id. Must i generate all the tables before to find them on runtime ?

Comment: That's what I did for my project, I has a separate code for creating all the structure of my table and then control the data using JPA.